# ¿Como se prueba un repository void en Java usando JUnit y Mock?

Tags: java, mockito, junit-5

Tengo el siguiente método en Java que se encarga de consultar al repository paa realizar un update a la BD, y estoy haciendo su prueba unitaria, pero al usar el **Mockito.when** me dice que no es aplicable para metodos void, entonces no se como hacer el test de mi servicio

Clase ServiceImpl

```
    @Override
    public Response actualizaDatos(List<TiempoEntity> turnos) {
        Response response = new Response();
        try {
            for(TiempoEntity turno : turnos) {
                tiempoRepository.actualizaTiempo(turno.getHoraInicial(), turno.getTiempoEspera());
            }
            response.setMensaje("OK");
            response.setResultado(200);
        }catch(Exception e) {
            response.setMensaje("Ocurrio un error al actualizar los datos");
            response.setResultado(500);
        }
        
        return response;
    }
```

Repository

```
public interface TiempoRepository extends  JpaRepository<TiempoEntity, String>  {

        @Modifying
        @Transactional
        @Query(value = "update TiempoEntity set fdhorainicial = TO_DATE(:horaArranque,'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'), fdtiempoespera = TO_DATE(:tiempoEspera,'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'),nativeQuery = true)
        void actualizaTiempo(@Param("horaInicial") String horaInicial, @Param("tiempoEspera") String tiempoEspera);
    
    }
```

Clase Response

```
public class Response {
    
        private String mensaje;
        private Integer resultado;
    
    
        public String getMensaje() {
            return mensaje;
        }
        public void setMensaje(String mensaje) {
            this.mensaje = mensaje;
        }
        public Integer getResultado() {
            return resultado;
        }
        public void setResult(Integer resultado) {
            this.resultado = resultado;
        }
    }
```

Test

```
    @Test
    public void test() {
        TiempoEntity tiempo = new TiempoEntity();
        tiempo.setHoraInicial("1970/01/01 01:00:01");
        tiempo.setTiempoEspera("1970/01/01 00:10:11");
        List<TiempoEntity> lista = new ArrayList<TiempoEntity>();
        lista.add(tiempo);
        
        Mockito.when(tiempoRepository.actualizaTiempo("1970/01/01 01:00:01","1970/01/01 00:10:11"));
        
        Response response = new Response();
        response = service.actualizaDatos(lista);
        
    }
```

como puedo realizar el test de mi servicio para que cubra todo el método, incluyendo el caso de la excepcion?
como se prueba cuando el repository es de tipo void?

Comment: Pero... ¿quieres probar el repositorio o el servicio?

Comment: @E. Betanzos
 las dos cosas, es posible?

Comment: ¿Es podible? Pues claro, pero tendrías una prueba considerablemente extensa y poco útil, puesto que en vez de centrarse en probar un único aspecto estaría probando varios. Mi recomendación sería que por un lado pruebes el servicio usando un *mock* del repositorio y por otro lado pruebes que el repositorio funcione correctamente. De este modo tus pruebas te van a informar de un modo más preciso, cuando haya algún fallo, el origen del problema.

Answer (score 1):

En lugar de usar la llamada a `when()`, necesitas llamar a `doNothing()`, como sigue:

```
Mockito.doNothing().when(tiempoRepository).actualizaTiempo("1970/01/01 01:00:01","1970/01/01 00:10:11");
```

Ah, y para la excepción, ocupas `Mockito.doThrow()`

info: https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-void-methods